# Delete and repost the same answer

Tags: discussion, reposts

A user posts an answer that is wrong content-wise, meaning that it does not fit under any of the flags.  Now, it has received a huge amount of downvotes.  Can the user just delete it and add a new, exactly-the-same answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

He could - though it would likely still get a lot of downvotes if he didn't fix anything. If he made a habit of it - he'd probably be [answer banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th), so he couldn't post any more answers easily.

Reposting, as such, solves nothing for the user, and its more or less resolves itself eventually